# Adding a parameter to a pass through query

Tags: sql-server, openquery

I am trying to use parameters within a pass through query the issue is when I set the statement up I get

> Incorrect syntax near '+'. Expecting ')'

I've done this before so I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly now. I've shortened the query below to give the gist.

```
DECLARE @WORK_DATE AS VARCHAR(20)

SET @WORK_DATE = '20160210'

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DATA_BASE_1,
  'SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS EMPLOYEE_ID
  FROM TABLE_1 EMPLOYEE
  LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 PERSON
  ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = PERSON.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
  AND PERSON.WORK_DATE = '''''+ @WORK_DATE + '''''')
```

Comment: You can't use variables in `OPENQUERY`. Try using dynamic SQL. e.g. `DECLARE @WORK_DATE AS VARCHAR(20)

SET @WORK_DATE = '2002-11-21 00:00:00'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = 
'SELECT *  FROM OPENQUERY(Database1,
''SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS EMPLOYEE_ID
FROM TABLE_1 EMPLOYEE
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 PERSON
ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = PERSON.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER
AND PERSON.WORK_DATE =''''' + @WORK_DATE + ''''''')'
EXEC(@SQL)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Transact-SQL OPENQUERY documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx):

> **Remarks**
>
> OPENQUERY does not accept variables for its arguments.

One way to do this would be to pass the variable to a string storing the query to be executed and then execute it.

```
DECLARE @SQL_TO_EXEC NVARCHAR(MAX), @WORK_DATE VARCHAR(20)

SET @WORK_DATE = '20160210'
SET @SQL_TO_EXEC = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DATA_BASE_1, ''SELECT EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AS EMPLOYEE_ID FROM TABLE_1 EMPLOYEE LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 PERSON ON EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER = PERSON.EMPLOYEE_NUMBER AND PERSON.WORK_DATE = '''''+ @WORK_DATE + ''''''')'

EXEC (@SQL_TO_EXEC)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, I googled all over could not find much on Pass Through with variables so thank you.